# iframe links to not open in new window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i is possible to force iframe to open links inside iframe window . 
means when i click link in iframe it opens link in same window but not in iframe . i want that when i click link it should open link in same iframe .
i don't want to edit some code in links cause there are too many links so i can;t edit that.???

so it is possible to make so this thing by changing code in i frame or using javescript in i frame ???

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the [tag:java] tag from your question. If I am wrong and this is truly a Java question, then re-add it, and comment back to me to let me know that I'm mistaken. If I'm right, then you will want to take care to give your question accurate flags as this gives your question the best opportunity to attract the correct experts.

Comment: `iframe`s are generally pretty well sandboxed. Not sure, but I think this isn't possible without trickery.

Answer (score 0):

This code works good for me, your iframe must contain a page from the same domain, and don't froget to set the id of your iframe to `id="iframe"`

```
$(document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a")).click
(
   function()
   { 
        document.location.href=$(this).attr('href'); 
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using the parent attribute on the link inside your demo_iframe.htm page. For example:

<a target="_parent" href="http://www.example.com">link</a>

Hope this helps.